# Compare dates in different years php

Tags: php, date, compare

I need to compare dates in separate years so that I can trigger an different event in a different year, however, php doesn't recognise the comparison between the dates in different years.

Below is what i'm trying to execute;

```
$priceSwitchDate = date('d-m-Y',strtotime('01-01-2018'));
$dateNow = date('d-m-Y'); // currently today (in 2017)

if($dateNow >= $priceSwitchDate){ echo 'date is in 2018 change prices';}
 else { echo 'date is in 2017, keep prices the same'; }
```

When i run the code it always seems to think that the date today (in 2017) is more than the `$priceSwitchDate` (in 2018).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Stop formatting dates as d-m-Y if you want to compare them.... either compare the timestamps, or use DateTime objects that can be directly compared

Comment: why not if(date('Y') === '2018') ?

Comment: Yes Azjezz, that's what i reverted to (just comparing the years). It works but i was concerned it was a hacky way to do it. Wasn't sure if there was a more compliant way to achieve the result